# Random permutation of letters

Tags: java

I have cities: A, B, C, D, E

How can I generate an initial solution in Java that contains all of these elements once? For example: BCDAE

Currently I'm generating a solution in order ABCDE then mixing it up, is there an easier way to do this I'm just not thinking of?

Comment: Is this anything to do with the TSP itself?  Or are you just asking "how do I randomly rearrange the letters ABCDE?"

Comment: I guess. I'm just wondering if there is a more optimised way of doing what I'm doing my code seems a little complex for the problem at hand.

Comment: Well, TSP is a complex problem. Still I don't see how randomly permutating the input list is going to solve it. If at all, you'd have to systematically test all permutations.

Comment: I'm building a hill climbing algorithm and I'm trying to generate a random initial solution for the hill climber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the Collections API to give me a one-liner:

```
List<String> letters;
Collections.shuffle(letters);
```

[`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) puts the elements in a random order.

Here's a little test. Every time you run this, you'll get random order output:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<String> letters = Arrays.asList( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" );
    Collections.shuffle( letters );
    System.out.println( letters );
}
```